# javascript bluebird promise -> get first file from list async

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, mocha.js, bluebird

I am trying to use promises with javascript to get from a list of paths (i.e. ["c:\\temp\\test1.json", "c:\\temp\\test2.json"]) the first file that is available on disc (i.e. c:\temp\test2.json).

```
function getFirstFile(paths) {

    if (!paths || paths.length == 0) {
        return {};
    }

    // sequential async search (recursive)
    var filePath = paths.shift();
    return fs.readFileAsync(filePath)
        // found = stop searching
        .then(function (content) {
            return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(content));
            })
        })
       // continue searching further paths left in the list
       .error(function (err) {
            return getFirstFile(paths);
       });
 }    

var paths2 = ["c:\\temp\\test1.json", "c:\\temp\\test2.json"];

getFirstFile(paths2)
    .then( function (index) {
        assert.equal(index.file, ".test2.json");
    })
    .error( function(err) {
        assert.fail(err.toString());
    });
```

For some reason although the file "C:\temp\test2.json" is available the fs.readFileAsync(filePath) does not enter the .then(function (content) {

...it is like the promise has en exception or something that is not caught?

Comment: Maybe `JSON.parse` throws an exception?

Comment: Forgot to mention I use Mocha and Node.js with bluebird as promises lib.

Comment: So is what do you files contain?

Comment: A json object ... the content is some configuration that actually does not matter as it parses OK.
    {
        "file" : "test2.json"
    }

Answer (score 1):

For clarity -> the code below works OK without Mocha testing. When integrated in Mocha the test passes OK whatever I do have test2.json.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');  //much faster than Chrome native promises
if (typeof fs.readFileAsync === "undefined") {Promise.promisifyAll(fs);}  // generate Async methods from callbacks
var path = require('path');

function getFirstFile(paths) {

    if (!paths || paths.length == 0) {
        return {};
    }
    // sequential async search (recursive)
    var filePath = paths.shift();
    return fs.readFileAsync(filePath)
        // found = stop searching
        .then(function (content) {
            return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(content));
            })
        })
        // continue searching further paths left in the list
        .error(function (err) {
            return getFirstFile(paths);
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            return getFirstFile(paths);
        });
}

var paths2 = ["c:\\temp\\test1.json", "c:\\temp\\test2.json"];

getFirstFile(paths2)
.then( function (index) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(index));
})
.error( function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The error was how the Mocha test was invoked (see the wrong and good test code).

Wrong code (Mocha will always pass since the promise returns after the test):

```
it('My Test', function () {    
    utils.getFirstFile(["c:\\temp\\test1.json", "c:\\temp\\test2.json"])
    .then(function(index) {
        assert.equal(index.file, ".test2.json");
    })
    .catch( ....);
}
```

Correct code is (return a promise):

```
it('My Test', function () {    
    return utils.getFirstFile(["c:\\temp\\test1.json", "c:\\temp\\test2.json"])
        .then(function(index) {
             assert.equal(index.file, ".test2.json");
        });
}
```

Comment: Is this a solution? If no, it should not be posted as an answer, please edit your question instead.

Comment: Yes I added the solution and the reasons of my error in the solution.

Comment: Ah, that's what I suspected in my comment above, that you forgot the `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's likely that the promise ended up rejecting (JSON.parse probably threw an error that caused a rejection), but because of this

```
   .error(function (err) {
        return getFirstFile(paths);
   });
```

The rejection would be caught, and the function ran again, and again. It would forever run in a loop, never actually reaching the rejection. You need to let the promise reject.

Comment: It is not that. when I run this without Mocha it works OK. The json file is parsable.

Comment: It doesn't matter, what happens when it works correctly. Try it with invalid input. File with invalid JSON, all files invalid, and you'll see that your promise won't reach the `.then()` or the `.error()` block outside of the function.

Comment: At each loop the list of "paths" is smaller so it does not run forever but stops when empty. I understand your point and you are right about .catch. Thank you for the hint. However the issue is with Mocha testing....I think i will unittest directly and drop Mocha.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.error()` method](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#error-rejectedhandler----promise) "*only catches [operational errors](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#operationalerror)*", an exception from `JSON.parse` wouldn't be caught. You should use the [`.catch()` method](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#catchfunction-handler---promise) instead - at least in your final handler that calls `assert.fail`.

```
function getFirstFile(paths) {
    if (!paths || paths.length == 0) return {};

    // sequential async search (recursive)
    var filePath = paths.shift();
    return fs.readFileAsync(filePath)
    .then(JSON.parse)
    .catch(function (err) {
        return getFirstFile(paths);
    });
}

getFirstFile(["c:\\temp\\test1.json", "c:\\temp\\test2.json"])
.then(function(index) {
    assert.equal(index.file, ".test2.json");
})
.catch(function(err) {
    assert.fail(err.toString());
});
```

Comment: The test passes Ok whatever I put there:     assert.equal(index.file, ".testXXX.json");  this is hat I do not understand...the code seems correct since without Mocha it works OK....but not in Mocha

Comment: You may want to `return` the promise to the mocha test runner?

Comment: What exactly does not work OK in Mocha, you say the test passes?